# redirect after login Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i cant make my code to redirect after succesfully login
code:

```
function check() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  var userPw = document.getElementById("userPw").value;
  var userFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].email == userName && users[i].pw == userPw) {
      userFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (userFound) {
    alert("Inicio de sesion correcto");
    window.location.href = "../feed.html";
  } else {
    alert("Esa cuenta no está registrada");
  }
}
```

i've tried window.location window.replace and everything

Comment: did you debug to know which alert block shows up on the window, first or second?

Comment: Inspect your code and take a look at the console if you get any errors regarding your redirect. If you are still stuck then please post the console logs also in your question.

Comment: How do you call check(), via button? Do you use a form? However, you can try changing button type to `type='button'` or adding `return false;` to the very bottom of your function.

Comment: 1. what's the error message? 2. do you have set the proper path for the file (outside the folder : ../feed.html)? 3. is it localhost or online? 4. have you tried setting up the complete url to the file (ie: www.mydomain.com/myfolder/feed.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I was late, but looking out for your code, you didn't attach your html data.

So, here's how I check.

First, maybe your `onclick` function is inside your `form`.

Doing an `onclick` inside the form, `window.location.href` actually do not work.

How i get it? here's the sample.

```js
function check() {
  let users = [
    {email: 'sample@yahoo.com', pw: 'sample123'}
  ];
  var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  var userPw = document.getElementById("userPw").value;
  var userFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].email == userName && users[i].pw == userPw) {
      userFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (userFound) {
    alert("Inicio de sesion correcto");
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
  } else {
    alert("Esa cuenta no está registrada");
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label>User Name: </label><input id="userName" type="email" required>
  <br>
  <label>Password: </label><input id="userPw" type="password" required>
  <br>
  <button onClick="check()" id="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

See, it didn't go to the link.

Now, doing it outside or without form,

```js
function check() {
  let users = [
    {email: 'sample@yahoo.com', pw: 'sample123'}
  ];
  var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  var userPw = document.getElementById("userPw").value;
  var userFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].email == userName && users[i].pw == userPw) {
      userFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (userFound) {
    alert("Inicio de sesion correcto");
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Esa cuenta no está registrada");
  }
}
```

```html
<label>User Name: </label><input id="userName" type="email" required>
  <br>
<label>Password: </label><input id="userPw" type="password" required>
<br>
<button onClick="check()" id="btn">Submit</button>
```

It actually work.

Then how to do it inside the form?

1. In your `button` add `return` before the function.
2. Add `return false;` after the `window.location.href` so it will not do the action from your `form`.

```js
function check() {
  let users = [
    {email: 'sample@yahoo.com', pw: 'sample123'}
  ];
  var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  var userPw = document.getElementById("userPw").value;
  var userFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].email == userName && users[i].pw == userPw) {
      userFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (userFound) {
    alert("Inicio de sesion correcto");
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Esa cuenta no está registrada");
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label>User Name: </label><input id="userName" type="email" required>
  <br>
  <label>Password: </label><input id="userPw" type="password" required>
  <br>
  <button onClick="return check()" id="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```